# Получить output из powershell при запуске из Python

Tags: python, powershell

Есть код на запуск powershell команды в python. Он работает, но достает вывод с типом Bytes.

1. Может есть какой-то способ получить вывод команды в строку или список?

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "Get-ADComputer -identity 12345_123_1 -properties *"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p_out, p_err = p.communicate()
    print(p_out)
    p_out = p_out.decode('ascii')
    print(p_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
p = subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", "Get-ADComputer -identity 12345_123_1 -properties *"], universal_newlines=True)
print(p)
```